# Java - eleven random numbers between 0-9

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to create an ID number for Map , so basically I have Customer class , and Map which will contain all the customers with String name , Double balance and int idNumber , the problem is that idNumber must be a collection of random numbers between 0-9 : example : 01019074902 . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its will generate 11 digit Random Numbers

```
long randomNumber = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9_000_000_0000L) + 1_000_000_0000L;
```